# Oracle data pump import/export parameters

Tags: oracle, impdp

When I was going through a data pump import parameter file, I came across the below line,

```
EXCLUDE=TABLE/TABLE
```

I would like to know the purpose of this line or the effect to import process if the line is removed.

Answer (score 0):

`EXCLUDE`
Default: none

Syntax:

```
EXCLUDE=object_type[:name_clause]
```

Purpose:
Enables you to filter the metadata that is exported by specifying objects and object types that you want excluded from the export operation. If an object is excluded, all of its dependent objects are also excluded. For example, excluding a table will also exclude all indexes and triggers on the table.